# How to merge pandas columns and merge datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have from a csv file a dataframe like this :

```
Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1  Temp    Hi   Low  Out  Dew   Wind Wind.1 Wind.2   Hi.1  ...   In    In In .1 In .2 In .3   In Air Unnamed: 30 Wind.4 Wind.5    ISS   Arc.

   0        Date       Time   Out  Temp  Temp  Hum  Pt.  Speed    Dir    Run  Speed  ...  Temp  Hum   Dew  Heat   EMC  Density         ET    Samp    Tx   Recept  Int.

   1    09/04/19      11:05   ---   ---   ---  ---  ---    0.0    ---   0.00    0.0  ...  27.8   30   8.6  26.6  6.05   1.1483        0.00      0      1     0.0     5

   2    09/04/19      11:10   ---   ---   ---  ---  ---    0.0    ---   0.00    0.0  ...  28.1   29   8.4  26.8  5.85   1.1475        0.00      0      1     0.0     5

   3    09/04/19      11:15   ---   ---   ---  ---  ---    0.0    ---   0.00    0.0  ...  28.2   29   8.5  27.0  5.85   1.1468        0.00      0      1     0.0     5
```

I would like to have a numpy array of containing a datetime of each measurement. How to merge the two first columns containing distinctively date and time. Thanks for any help on this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need it as a string then

```
df["Date_Time"] = df["Date"].map(str) + ' ' + df["Time"].map(str)
```

But if you want to retain the date format then try the code below which will create a new column Date_Time with datetime64[ns] format.

```
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['Time'])
```

Comment: Your second solution is working when i isolate it. But in my class I have this error :
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar thing, I used a "helper" column datetime

```
df['helper']=df.Date+' '+df.Time

       date   time        helper
 1  09/04/19  11:15  09/04/19 11:15
 2  09/04/19  11:05  09/04/19 11:05
```

and then

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.helper)

1   2019-09-04 11:15:00
2   2019-09-04 11:05:00
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and finally

```
df.drop(columns='helper', inplace=True)
```

Comment: When I try to add a datetime columns I've this error :
"ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1"

Comment: Which line gives you ValueError?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.apply(axis=1)` to create a new pandas series based on the values from multiple columns. In your case, it could look something like this:

```python
def merge_datetime(row):
    date = row['Date']
    time = row['Time']
    return pd.to_datetime(f'{date} {time}')

datetimes = df.apply(merge_datetime, axis=1)

datetimes.values # numpy array
```